# How can I add a link to download a file in a Django admin detail page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to create a file containing a string and allow the user to download the file when they click a button in the admin detail page. Any ideas?

Probably add html to the form? But how can I do that? I am new to Django.

Comment: What do you mean by `in the admin form`? In admin list page or in admin detail page?

Comment: admin detail page, where I can edit model fields and save the changes.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: @Selcuk I need to add the button in the admin detail page, not in the list page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can go along the following lines:

```
class YourAdmin(ModelAdmin):   
     # add the link to the various fields attributes (fieldsets if necessary)
    readonly_fields = ('download_link',)
    fields = (..., 'download_link', ...)

    # add custom view to urls
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(YourAdmin, self).get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^download-file/(?P<pk>\d+)$', self.download_file, 
                name='applabel_modelname_download-file'),
        ]
        return urls

    # custom "field" that returns a link to the custom function
    def download_link(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{}">Download file</a>',
            reverse('admin:applabel_modelname_download-file', args=[obj.pk])
        )
    download_link.short_description = "Download file"

    # add custom view function that downloads the file
    def download_file(self, request, pk):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="whatever.txt"')
        # generate dynamic file content using object pk
        response.write('whatever content')
        return response
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `admin:applabel_modelname_download-file` does?

Comment: This is the name of the view as it is used by `reverse` or the `url` templatetag. The [common admin views follow that the `applabel_modelname_viewname` pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). That's why I used it.

Comment: I am getting `No Reverse match` error. I am using `Model.__meta.app_label` value for `applabel` and for `modelname` the actual model name in lowercase. I wrote `download-file` just like you did. Did I miss something?

Comment: I did the same but now, when I try to add an object, I am getting `No Reverse match`.

Comment: For all who are getting No Reverse math when adding new objects: In `download_link` function put `if obj.id is not None then return link` otherwise return `"-"`.

Comment: **Important note**, a url / path added like this is not secured! You have to manually add the [`@staff_member_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.views.decorators.staff_member_required) decorator (for example) to have it secured against anonymous and non-staff-member requests. If you do nothing, this file download is accessible for _everyone_.

Answer (score 4):

In your `models.py` field for that application, add the following piece of code

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def fieldname_download(self):
    return mark_safe('<a href="/media/{0}" download>{1}</a>'.format(
        self.fieldname, self.fieldname))

fieldname_download.short_description = 'Download Fieldname'
```

Then in your `admin.py`, add this field to your readonly_fields for that model

```
readonly_fields = ('fieldname_download', )
```

In your `settings.py` file you need to specify a root path to a directory where to serve the files from and a base url for accessing them:

```py
MEDIA_ROOT=(str, 'path/to/your/media/directory/'),
MEDIA_URL=(str,'/media/'),
```

Comment: Seems like I also need to add `fieldname_download` to the `fields` attribute, any idea why?.

Comment: If you've defined the `fields` option in the custom admin for that model, then you need to add `fieldname_download` to it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields

Answer (score 1):

There are two answer about add download link as new field to details page which is easyer than add download link inside `AdminFileWidget`. I write this answer in case someone need add download link inside `AdminFileWidget`.
The final result like this:

[image]

The way to achieve this is:

1 `models.py`:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                            verbose_name='name')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=attachment_file,
                            null=True,
                            verbose_name='file ')
```

2 views.py:

```
class AttachmentView(BaseContextMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = Attachment.objects.all()
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if settings.DEBUG:
            response = HttpResponse(instance.file, content_type='application/force-download')
        else:
            # x-sendfile is a module of apache,you can replace it with something else
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download')
            response['X-Sendfile'] = instance.file.path
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(urlquote(instance.filename))
        return response
```

3 urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('attachment/<int:pk>/', AttachmentView.as_view(), name='attachment'),
]
```

4 admin.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib.admin import widgets


class DownloadFileWidget(widgets.AdminFileWidget):
    id = None
    template_name = 'widgets/download_file_input.html'

    def __init__(self, id, attrs=None):
        self.id = id
        super().__init__(attrs)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        print(self, name, value, attrs, self.id)
        context['download_url'] = reverse('attachment', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
        return context

class AttachmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', '_get_download_url']
    search_fields = ('name',)
    my_id_for_formfield = None

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.my_id_for_formfield = obj.id
        return super(AttachmentAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if self.my_id_for_formfield:
            if db_field.name == 'file':
                kwargs['widget'] = DownloadFileWidget(id=self.my_id_for_formfield)

        return super(AttachmentAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

    def _get_download_url(self, instance):
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', reverse('attachment', kwargs={'pk': instance.id}), instance.filename)

    _get_download_url.short_description = 'download'

admin.site.register(Attachment, AttachmentAdmin)
```

5 download_file_input.html

```
{% include "admin/widgets/clearable_file_input.html" %}
<a href="{{ download_url }}">Download {{ widget.value }}</a>
```

That's all!