# Django render to PDF with foreign key

Tags: django, pdf, django-admin

I want to render to PDF the `nome` of `pavimento` on `AvariaAdmin`, and i really dont know how to do that.

http://prntscr.com/mmm5eo

**MY models**

```html
class Avaria(models.Model):

    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Freguesia")
    rua = models.ForeignKey(Rua, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Rua")
    porta = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Numero de polícia")
    tipo_avaria = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_avaria, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Tipos de avaria")
```

```html
class Pavimentacao(models.Model):

    avaria = models.ForeignKey(Avaria, related_name='AvariaObjects',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pavimento = models.ForeignKey(Pavimento, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Pavimento")
```

```html
class Pavimento(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField("Pavimento",max_length=200)
```

**MY DEF (INSIDE OF AvariaAdmin)**

```html
def Imprimir(self, request, obj):
    data = {
            'obj':obj
    }
    pdf = render_to_pdf('daa/imprimir/avarias_pdf.html', data)
    if pdf :
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename ="Avaria_%s.pdf" %("123451231")
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return  response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**MY HTML**

```html
        <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID:</th>
                    <th>Freguesia:</th>
                    <th>Rua:</th>  
                    <th>Porta:</th>
                    <th>Tipo avaria:</th>
                    <th>Pavimento:</th>
                 </tr>
                 {% for item in obj %}
                    <tr> 
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>   
                        <td>{{item.freguesia }}</td>
                        <td>{{item.rua}}</td> 
                        <td>{{item.porta}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.tipo_avaria}} </td>
                        <td>{{item.pavimento}} </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}    

        </table>
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: do you want a button in admin to render the PDF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a link to download a file in a Django admin detail page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492206/how-can-i-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-in-a-django-admin-detail-page)

Comment: @c.grey like in screenshot , i just want to display the name of the `pavimento` on AvariaAdmin and reder to pdf

Comment: @dirkgroten i have an action to render to pdf and it is already working , i just want to display the name of `pavimento` on my html , and like the screenshot , dont show any name. I have relationship where one `Avaria` can have  several `Pavimentacao` and when i print i want to show the names of `Pavimentos`

Comment: @dirkgroten well i want to render to pdf the `nome` of  `pavimentos`, and i wanted to show my `def` where i render already my obj to pdf. I want to know how i can render another obj with foreign key in the same html. 
Sorry if I built the question wrong.

Comment: ok, but what is `obj`? I mean which model? It looks like it's a list of `Avaria` instances? In which case you would need to loop through the related objects inside your `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's no need for the class `Pavimentacao` if that's all it contains (but maybe you didn't show us all the model). It's just holding a many-to-many relationship between `Avaria` and `Pavimento` which you should model directly with a `models.ManyToManyField`:

```
class Avaria(Model):
    ...
    pavimentos = models.ManyToManyField(Pavimento)
```

Then in your template, if you want to print all the `Pavimento` instances:

```
<tr>
    ...
    <td>
        {% for pavimento in item.pavimentos.all %}
            {{ pavimento.nome }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

But if you leave your models as they are now, the template code would be:

```
<tr>
    ...
    <td>
        {% for pavimentacao in item.AvariaObjects.all %}  <!-- this is because of the related_name you defined -->
            {{ pavimentacao.pavimento.nome }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

See how the `related_name` you gave is wrong? `related_name` is for the reverse relationship so it should be the name of the model you're defining, not the one you're referring to. Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) to understand reverse relationships.

Comment: I have this relationship because I have other fields that I did not show because they are not important. I tried this and it's giving me error `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot `all`

Comment: but you should still change the `related_name`, since they are not `AvariaObjects` but `Pavimentacao` instances. Or if you remove `related_name`, then the default related manager would be `pavimentacao_set`

Comment: yeh it is working , i will change it , i use `AvariaObjects` in other `def´s` and i think i will change everything , very thank you for your help , and sorry for the bad question construction

Comment: I have another problem that I still can not resolve, in another question , if you got time , i will be appreciate.