# Download a file after saving a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, weasyprint

I'm trying to generate a PDF based on a ModelForm using [Weasyprint](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/). The idea is when the user clicks save the PDF is generated after the model is saved (I'm using the signal `post_save` to accomplish this). But when I hit the save button, the model is saved but the download prompt is not shown to the user, even though I have the correct `Content-Disposition` configuration in my HttpResponse.

I also need to pass some parameters to the `post_save` signal because some of the fields that need to be added to the PDF are not in the Model, but are in the ModelForm, and I have not been able to find out how to do that.

admin.py

```
def save_model(self, request: HttpRequest, obj: Contract, form: ContractForm, change: Any) -> None:
        if not change and not request.user.is_superuser:
            obj = MythLabsMultiTenancy.assign_organization_to_obj(
                obj, request.user
            )
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

forms.py

```
from dal.autocomplete import ModelSelect2
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class ContractForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'handover_vehicle': ModelSelect2(
                url='vehicle_autocomplete', forward=('organization',),
            ),
            'lease_holder': ModelSelect2(
                url='client_autocomplete', forward=('organization',),
            ),
            'replacement_vehicle': ModelSelect2(
                url='replacement_vehicle_autocomplete', forward=('organization',),
            ),
        }

    warranty_card_company = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Tarjeta')
    warranty_card_number = forms.CharField(
        max_length=19, required=False, label='N° de tarjeta'
    )
    warranty_card_expiration_date = forms.CharField(
        max_length=5, required=False, label='Fecha de expiración',
        help_text='Formato: MM/YY',
        validators=[RegexValidator("(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{2}")]
    )
    warranty_card_auth_code = forms.IntegerField(
        max_value=9999, min_value=0, required=False,
        label='Código de autorización'
    )
```

signals.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.db.models import QuerySet
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from weasyprint import HTML

from .models import Charge, Contract, Control, Extension


@receiver(post_save, sender=Contract, dispatch_uid='download_contract_pdf')
def download_contract_pdf(sender, instance, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
    file_name = f"contrato-{datetime.now()}.pdf"
    key_list = [
        'warranty_card_company', 'warranty_card_number',
        'warranty_card_expiration_date', 'warranty_card_auth_code'
    ]
    credit_card_data = []
    # for key, value in instance.items:
    #     if key in key_list:
    #         credit_card_data.append(value)
    charge_qs: QuerySet = Charge.objects.filter(contract=instance.pk)
    control_qs: QuerySet = Control.objects.filter(contract=instance.pk)
    extension_qs: QuerySet = Extension.objects.filter(contract=instance.pk)
    html_string = render_to_string(
        'pdf_template.html', {
            'charge_obj': charge_qs,
            'contract_obj': instance,
            'control_obj': control_qs,
            'extension_obj': extension_qs,
            'credit_card_data': credit_card_data
        }
    )
    html = HTML(string=html_string)
    pdf = html.write_pdf(
        stylesheets=[
            "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
    )
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{file_name}"',
    })
    return response
```

If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue! All I had to do is use `response_add` and `response_change` in my ModelAdmin.

```
def response_add(self, request: HttpRequest, obj: Contract, post_url_continue: None) -> HttpResponse:
    super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
    return generate_contract_pdf(request, obj, None)

def response_change(self, request: HttpRequest, obj: Contract) -> HttpResponse:
    super().response_change(request, obj)
    return generate_contract_pdf(request, obj, None)
```

Documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your file name in double quotes:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{file_name}"'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have added the double quotes to the filename but it did not work. I have edited my question with the changes I have made to `response['Content-Disposition']`

Comment: Hmm, the documentation sets the content type like so: `headers={'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}`, maybe try that just in case

Comment: I have tried that too and it did not work either, I have updated the code in my question, now it is written just like Django's documentation.

Comment: Are you using a `<a href>` tag in your template to call the function? I have almost identical code and it works just fine

Comment: I'm not using any specific template, I'm just using the default save button that comes with Django admin

Comment: Oh that explains things, does this question help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492206/how-can-i-add-a-link-to-download-a-file-in-a-django-admin-detail-page

Comment: No, I have tried implementing the post you suggested me but it is not what i want. I want to prompt a download window when the user hits Save, That post creates a link in the formset.

Comment: I think you’ll need to customise the admin page template in that case, it won’t just download from clicking save